# C# Newtonsoft JsonSerializationException when deserializing a serialized string

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I must be making a stupid mistake. When I run:

```
JsonResponse testREsponse = new JsonResponse
            {
                StartTimeUtc = 1,
                EndTimeUtc = 1,
                TimeResolutionInMilliseconds = 60000,
                Results = new JsonResults
                {
                    Type = "hello",
                    Values = new List<EvaluatedResult>()
                }
            };
            string convertTest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testREsponse);
            Console.WriteLine("HRMM " + convertTest);
            JsonResponse jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(convertTest);
```

I'm getting a

```
Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'JarvisReader.JsonResults' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
```

when trying to deserialize a string that I serialized the line above. It's indicating 'Path 'results.$values', line 1, position 71.' which would be the results bracket.

Objects:

```
class JsonResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("startTimeUtc")]
    public long StartTimeUtc { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("endTimeUtc")]
    public long EndTimeUtc { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public JsonResults Results { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("timeResolutionInMilliseconds")]
    public int TimeResolutionInMilliseconds { get; set; }
}

class JsonResults
{
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$values")]
    public List<EvaluatedResult> Values { get; set; }
}

class EvaluatedResult
{
    [JsonProperty("dimensionList")]
    public DimensionList dimensionList { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("evaluatedResult")]
    public decimal evaluatedResult { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("seriesValues")]
    public List<Decimal> seriesValues { get; set; }
}

class DimensionList
{
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$values")]
    public List<Dimension> values;
}

class Dimension
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string key { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I condensed my testREsponse to be almost empty. And it looks like it serializes just fine.

```
{"startTimeUtc":1,"endTimeUtc":1,"results":{"$type":"hello","$values":[]},"timeResolutionInMilliseconds":60000}
```

When I remove JsonResults from the construction, it serializes and deserializes just fine. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(convertTest, new JsonSerializerSettings { MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore });
```

$ indicates metadata.  The serializer setting makes the value get treated like a property.

Comment: oh my... Thank you so much. 2 days of frustration resolved. I could not figure out why testing with JsonProperty("$value") was working but not '$values' (but actual usage requires '$values'). Thanks. I never even thought to consider metadata.